# Can't change Customer's Customer Tax Class

Tags: magento-1.7, customer, tax, class

I have this weird problem where I can't change a customer's Customer Tax Class through the admin interface. It keeps jumping back to Retail customer.

So when I select a different Customer Tax Class and press save, it just stays at Retail customer.

Even when I update the customer's Customer Tax Class through the database with an SQL query (shown below), it works and does change the Customer Tax Class of the customer, but when I go back to the interface, and press the "Save Customer" button (in case I would like to edit some other information) it will jump back to the wrong Customer Tax Class, "Retail Customer".

```
UPDATE `customer_entity` SET tax_class_id = MY_TAX_CLASS_ID 
WHERE entity_id = CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ID
```

I checked the Customer Group settings, and for that Customer Group, I set the default Customer Tax Class to the one I actually want, but even then it keeps jumping back to Retail Customer.

I haven't set up this installation so a previous manager might have set up a limitation somewhere? I don't know.

Thanks in advance, this stackexchange board has been of great help trying to unravel the enigmatic spaghetti which is Magento.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked custom modules to make sure there is not some observer changing this value?

Comment: Is there a quick way to look for this? Since I'm not the original developer and there are a lot of modules.

Comment: No gaurantee this would find it, but search app/code/local and app/code/community for anything mentioning tax_class_id

Comment: It took a while but finally found it :) thanks